# How to make visible private classes into specific stylesheet?

Tags: next.js

Is it possible to access css classes from css modules in a specific css stylesheet? For example I have mediaQueries.css witch I want to connect at the end of my markup of components, but I can't see within mediaQueries.css private classes of aboute.module.css or index.module.css. So how can I configure webpack or what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Import them as an object and reference the classes as properties:

```js
import styles from "./path/to/stylesheet.module.css";

export default function Component() {
    return <div className={styles.className}>hello world</div>
}
```

Example CSS:

```css
.className {
    color: red;
}
```

For regular stylesheets just import the CSS file:

```js
import "./path/to/stylesheet.css";
```